# Retrieve calling Activity from Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am trying to pass along my activity pointer in my intent but I don't know how to retrieve it.

I have a calling activity (MyActivity) with the following snippet of code:

```
Intent myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, myService.class);
startService(myServiceIntent);
```

In my service class I want to retrieve the calling activity. 
Something like this:

```
private Activity CurrentActivity = null;    
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        CurrentActivity = (CurrentActivity) intent.getClass();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

This doesn't work but I also don't know what does. 
I also couldn't find a putExtra that takes an activity as parameter.
So how can I do this?

Comment: You don't want to send an `Activity` reference in an `Intent`. Please explain why you think you want to do this and we can suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first activity take a static activity variable like this,

```
public static Activity activity;
```

In the onCreate do this.

```
activity = this;
```

Then in the second activity do this,

```
Activity activity = (your activity name).activity;
```

This is the best solution according to my little knowledge. Just pass a code/value for the varification like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("someValue", "data");
```

And in the second activity check the value, if the value is your required value then get your required activity instance. I hope this will solve your problem and if it will, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I found another way to achieve what I was doing so I didn't need to do this.
However this seems to work, only thing to add is a typecast for the concrete Activity when calling a function or changing a variable, in the intent extra i can check which typecast to use. So thanks for the help!

Comment: You should never hold reference to the Activity in static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get information of calling activity

```
val uriString= intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just send the activity name in the extras like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, otherActivity.class).putExtra("from" , "previousActivity"));
```

and get extras in the current activity as

```
string act = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");

Class callerClass = Class.forName(caller);
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Although I don't know how to convert the class object to an Activity object (without creating a new instance).

Comment: Activity obj = (Activity) callerClass .newInstance();

Comment: This can't be right. OP wants to send an actual instance of the Activity in the Intent. Just putting the name of the activity class in the Intent so that the receiver can create a new instance won't help. Also, you cannot (properly) create an instance of an Android component (like `Activity`) by using `new` or `Class.newInstance()`. This will only call the object constructor, but will not set up the component's context properly. Only the Android framework can create instances of Android components.

Comment: This still does not fully solve my problem. Since I do not want to create a new instance of my Activity. I just want to pass some kind of reference of my excisting Activity to my Service.